# Bind GridView with many records

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which shows only 50 records at a time through paging. If i bind that to a source say containing 150 records, it works like charm but when the record size increases drastically to 10,00000, it took ages to load data.. So, i want to know is there any way of just loading 50 records at a time which are visible??

> **I want something like Lazy Loading or the feature of Virtualizing Stack
>   Panel in wpf.**

This is how i am binding to the GridView -

```
private void LoadCustomers()
        {            
            if (Cache["CustomersData"] == null)
            {
                Business.Customers customers = Business.Customers.GetAllCustomer();
                Cache["CustomersData"] = customers;
            }
            this.customerGridView.DataSource = Cache["CustomersData"];
            this.customerGridView.DataBind();  
        }
```

And here's the function which fetch data from DB-

```
public static Customers GetAllCustomer(int index)
        {
            Customers customers = new Customers();

        NShop_SmallEntities data = new NShop_SmallEntities();
        var dbCustomers = (from c in data.Customers
                            select c).OrderBy(c=> c.CustomerId).Skip(index * 50).Take(50);

        foreach (var dbCustomer in dbCustomers)
        {
            customers.Add(Customer.GetCustomer(dbCustomer));
        }

        return customers;
        }

public static Customer GetCustomer(DAL.Customer dbCustomer)
        {
            return new Customer()
                {
                    CustomerId = dbCustomer.CustomerId,
                    FirstName = dbCustomer.FirstName,
                    LastName = dbCustomer.LastName,
                    Email = dbCustomer.Email,
                    DOB = dbCustomer.DOB,
                    City = dbCustomer.City,
                    State = dbCustomer.State,
                    PostalCode = dbCustomer.PostalCode,
                    Country = dbCustomer.Country,
                    OrderCount = dbCustomer.Orders.Count()
                };
        }
```

Comment: What kind of DB: SQL Server, AS400...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is, accoring to your change, how I would do that :

```
public static Customers GetAllCustomer(int startIndex, int nbrOfResults, out total) {
   Customers customers = new Customers();

   NShop_SmallEntities data = new NShop_SmallEntities();
   var dbCustomers = from c in data.Customers
                     select c;

   // Retreiving total number of customers. NEEDED to get 
   // ObjectDataSource working.
   total = dbCustomers.Count();

   foreach (var dbCustomer in dbCustomers
                         .Skip((startIndex * nbrOfResults) + 1)
                         .Take(NumberOfResults).ToList() {
      customers.Add(Customer.GetCustomer(dbCustomer));
   }
   return customers;
}

/// <summary>
/// This methods must have the same signature than the "real" one... exept the name :oP
/// </summary>
public static int GetAllCustomerCount(int startIndex, int nbrOfResults, out total) {
      return (from c in data.Customers select c).Count();
}
```

And now in your page ;

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBulletins" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
   ObjectDataSourceID="objCustomersDS">
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objCustomersDS" runat="server" 
     SelectMethod="GetAllCustomer" SelectCountMethod="GetAllCustomerCount" 
     TypeName="AssemblyName" EnablePaging="True" MaximumRowsParameterName="nbrOfResults"
     StartRowIndexParameterName="startIndex">
    <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="startIndex" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="nbrOfResults" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="total" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks but this in not what i am looking for. I have updated my question to be more precise..

Comment: but how are you binding to your source? Is it Entity, SQL, etc? If it's an object datasource, it's may be because you return ALL your data and after you scoope into it.

Comment: Then in your GetAllCustomer function, add the skip and take parameters for the fetch. Otherwize, if you have 10,00000 entries, it return you, 10,000000 entries. Take and skip will scope exactly those and fetch ONLY those from DB... There for sur a difference between feltching 50-100-150 and 10,00000 entries!!

Comment: I have updated my GetAllCustomer to fetch only 50 records at a time but the issue now i facing is, the pagination is gone for the grid view because now the datasource of a grid view contain only 50 records, hence no pagination... :((

Comment: Heck yea ... that's why, when using object type source, you'll need to use an objectdatasource instead of binding it directly into the coutrol's datasource. Is it possible for you to use an ObjectDataSource? Because, when using this, you'll do all the paging by hand by adding a "CountMethod" which return the whole NUMBER (not objects) of results. In your case, "(from c in data.Customers select c).Count();"

Comment: And there's also a lot of other paramters to give to your objectdatasource. I'll post another answer soon with how to do this

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort to help me out constantly. Actually, i am new to asp.net. So, dont have that much hands on over an objectdatasource. So for now i'll stick to object source only but surely read over that too..

Comment: Paging with ObjectDataSource is a nightmare at the begining. Once you done it, stick to it and reuse it the same way eveytime and it will work like a charm! I've update my answer. For being there from not so long ... Amen.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon.. That really worked just like that.. :) Though i have changed a bit of your code as per my requirements. Marking as an answer..

Comment: @Simon - I have one more query which i posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604629/limit-response-time-of-my-sql-query Can you guide me through that too, that would be great.. :)

Comment: You seem to found it? Is it ok?