# Limit response time of my SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have posted a question here regarding binding of my gridview - [Bind GridView with many records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599704/bind-gridview-with-many-records/5599846#5599846) with number of visible records at a moment. The performance hit has come down incredibily to 2sec from 20sec by implementing the answer but still i know it can be lowered to more limit.

Like- When i fetch say 50 records(Customers) at a time from DB, it has one column which fetch number of orders corresponding to that customer from Orders table(just count not complete record). So, it hit 50 queries to a SQL Server to fetch data for 50 customers. Is there a way where i can fetch complete data with a single query??

NOTE- If someone needs to look at a code, do let me know. Hopefuly, the link which i have provided contains enough codebase..

Comment: It is likely you can do it all in one hit of the database however we'll need to see the query before one can say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Database Indexing` was what i was looking for.